# No puedo conectarme a base de datos en localhost

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu

Estoy creando una base de datos en local para unos proyectos y no puedo conectarme a la base de datos.

He instalado `PostgreSQL`
luego he entrado con el usuario postgres que se crea al isntalar

`su - postgres`

Después he utilizado el comando `psql` para entrar en la consola de sql donde he usado el comando `CREATE DATABASE mibasededatos;`

Una vez hecho esto, veo que poniendo el comando `\list`me aparece mi base de datos, sin embargo cuando intento conectarme a a ella desde DBeaver me dice que no se puede conectar.

Comment: Verificaste en que puerto se ejecuta `postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Siempre he tenido el mismo problema de conexión mediante Navicat y siempre lo he subsanado indicando, en vez de localhost la dirección ip de la base de datos.

Si esta opción te sigue sin funcionar comprueba los permisos de acceso a la base de datos, puede que tengas algo capado por defecto y no te hayas dado cuenta.

Salu2.

Comment: El problema es que el servidor local de mysql si que conecta, poniendo localhost o la 127.0.0.0 pero postgres no

Comment: Pues lo único que se me ocurre es que algún tipo de permiso o configuración de seguridad pueda estar capando la conexión.

Comment: Verifica el puerto con el cual estas intentando conectarte. Postgres maneja un puerto (5432) distinto al de MySQL. También intenta usar en lugar de localhost, la IP directamente.